# Group list of generic objects by its property

Tags: c#, generics

I have a question, I am trying to group a list of generic objects by certain key property that is inside those objects like:

```
    public void GroupChanges<TResult>(List<TResult> changes)
    {
        const string KeyPropertyName = "TransactionSequence";

        List<IGrouping<byte[], TResult>> changeSet = changes
            .GroupBy(change => /*change.TransactionSequence */ <- property avaible in every object that is 
                change.GetType().GetProperty(KeyPropertyName).GetValue(change)
                , new ArrayComparer<byte>())
            .ToList();
    }
```

Model of data and models is fairly simple I've got one abstract generic model above all other that contains Key property, models inherit that property and data is filled from Db and data structure is just a generic list of those models.

Now if I strongly type model its OK, how this can be changed?

Comment: I'm not sure but `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` will return object. Maybe you should cast that to `byte[]` to get the expected result.

Comment: Yes I tested it (have a look [here](https://ideone.com/YWAz7Y)). You only need to cast the result to `byte[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare an interface that is implemented by all the types you will pass to the method. And add it as a type constraint to your method. The you can access properties of the interface.

```
    interface ICommon
    {
        byte[] TransactionSequence { get; set; }
    }
    public void GroupChanges<TResult>(List<TResult> changes) 
         where TResult: ICommon 
    {
        List<IGrouping<byte[], TResult>> changeSet = changes
                .GroupBy(change => change.TransactionSequence , new ArrayComparer<byte>())
                .ToList();
    }
```

Note: The type constraint will also work an abstract/base class. This will not work if you LINQ over an IQueryable with EF

Comment: agreed, if you have enough things that implement `ICommon` it could be worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, if your function is generic, how does it know if `TResult` will have a `"TransactionSequence"` property? It cannot know this and be generic. Unless you put a constraint on the type, [see Titian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45955244/659190), this makes the function less generic but that could be useful.

You'd need to ask for a delegate like `Func<TResult, TProperty>` but then you might as well just call `GroupBy` directly.

Comment: This is a good approach if the function does some other work or you need to pass different properties. But if you always have the same member name and you can modify the existing classes to inherit the same class or implement an interface than type constraints are a better choice.